# Windows Server 2019 - Cannot take ownership of file

Tags: file-permissions, ownership, windows-server-2019

I know that this question has been asked before, but all threads are very old and none of the answers has fixed my problem. I was working on a Power BI report and all of a sudden found that my report file's permissions are changed. I cannot change its security/ownership:

Security tab:

[image: Security tab]

Advanced security tab:

[image: Advanced security tab]

Trying to change ownership:

[image: Trying to change ownership]

Methods I have tried so far:

- Administrative command prompt to run takeown
- Using Unlocker
- Closing and restarting explorer

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Try using an elevated Command Prompt and execute `takeown` command in combination with `calcs`:

```
takeown /F "ERP Reports.pbix"
```

And then:

```
cacls "ERP Reports.pbix" /g javaherizadeh.mohamm:f
```

If `/g` doesn't work, try `/p`.

Cacls manual at:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cacls

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Already tried this, no luck. First command says: Access denied

Comment: I don't know how and why, but the file is deleted! So, problem is gone!